# I want to echo message when form is submitted

Tags: php, forms, submit

I'm not very good at PHP (more of a front-end developer) and I'm doing a website for a client. I got everything working up to now except for one thing. When the user fills out the contact form and submits it successfully i want to display a message that tells them the email was sent. I already have the div set up I just don't know who to execute it with PHP.

```
<div class="sent">Email has been sent.</div>
    <form action="" method="POST" class="contact-form"> 
    <img class="close" src="images/close-icon.png">     
        <div class="top-title">Contact Us</div>
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="submit"> 
        <div class="input-title">Name*</div> 
        <input class="input" name="name" type="text" value="" size="30" required><br>
        <div class="input-title">Phone Number*</div> 
        <input class="input" name="phone" type="text" value="" size="30" required><br>
        <div class="input-title">Email Address*</div>
        <input class="input" name="email" type="text" value="" size="30" required><br> 
        <div class="input-title">How did you hear about us?</div>  
        <input class="input" name="company" type="text" value="" size="30"/><br> 
        <div class="input-title">Let us know how we can help you</div>
        <textarea class="textarea" name="message" rows="7" cols="30"></textarea><br> 
        <div class="required">*Fill is required</div>
        <input class="submit-button" type="submit" value="Send Email"/> 
    </form> 
    <?php              
        { 
        $name=$_POST['name']; 
        $email=$_POST['email']; 
        $phone=$_POST['phone']; 
        $company=$_POST['company']; 
        $message= "\r\nName: " . $_POST['name'] ."\r\nPhone Number: ". $_POST['phone']."\r\nEmail: ". $_POST['email'] ."\r\nHow you know the company: ".$_POST['company'] ."\r\nReason for message: ".$_POST['message'];

            $from="From: $name<$email>\r\nReturn-path: $email"; 
            $subject="GS Website Message"; 
            mail("name@email.com", $subject, $message, $from); 
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: `if(condition) { do something } else { do something else }` and apply that logic to your `mail()` function. *Teach a person HOW to fish...* I always say ;-)

Comment: Then you have braces `{code}` which should not be in there and you're most likely getting back undefined index notices, but you're not checking for errors http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php. Seeing you're using your HTML form and PHP inside the same file. You're also open to an XSS injection here in `$message...` so just use the variables you already declared them with.

Comment: I'm using an example i found online lol. Like I said I really have no idea how to code in PHP. The form actually works fine, it validates what i need and sends me all the fields values in an email. All i want to do is add a message when the form is submitted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change: (and using a conditional statement)

```
mail("name@email.com", $subject, $message, $from);
```

to:

```
if(mail("name@email.com", $subject, $message, $from)){
   $sent = "Message sent";
}
```

Then modify:

```
<div class="sent">Email has been sent.</div>
```

to read as:

```
<div class="sent"><?php if(!empty($sent)) { echo $sent; } ?></div>
```

Seeing you're new to PHP/forms, it's best to also check if your inputs are empty or not, otherwise you risk in either not getting mail, or receiving empty data.

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

Set inside a conditional statement also.

I.e.: using NOT empty: `!` is the NOT operator in PHP.

```
if(!empty($_POST['var'])){...}
```

---

**Edit:**

The logic needs to be reversed.

First, place your PHP above your HTML form.

I also added a `submit` name attribute to your submit button, with a conditional statement and a [ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) in the div.

```
<?php

 if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

        $name=$_POST['name']; 
        $email=$_POST['email']; 
        $phone=$_POST['phone']; 
        $company=$_POST['company']; 
        $message= "\r\nName: " . $_POST['name'] ."\r\nPhone Number: ". $_POST['phone']."\r\nEmail: ". $_POST['email'] ."\r\nHow you know the company: ".$_POST['company'] ."\r\nReason for message: ".$_POST['message'];

            $from="From: $name<$email>\r\nReturn-path: $email"; 
            $subject="GS Website Message"; 


if(mail("email@example.com", $subject, $message, $from)){

$sent = "Message sent";

    }
}
    ?> 

<div class="sent"><?php echo isset($sent) ? $sent : ''; ?></div>


    <form action="" method="POST" class="contact-form"> 

    <img class="close" src="images/close-icon.png">     


        <div class="top-title">Contact Us</div>
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="submit"> 
        <div class="input-title">Name*</div> 
        <input class="input" name="name" type="text" value="" size="30" required><br>
        <div class="input-title">Phone Number*</div> 
        <input class="input" name="phone" type="text" value="" size="30" required><br>
        <div class="input-title">Email Address*</div>
        <input class="input" name="email" type="text" value="" size="30" required><br> 
        <div class="input-title">How did you hear about us?</div>  
        <input class="input" name="company" type="text" value="" size="30"/><br> 
        <div class="input-title">Let us know how we can help you</div>
        <textarea class="textarea" name="message" rows="7" cols="30"></textarea><br> 
        <div class="required">*Fill is required</div>
        <input class="submit-button" type="submit" value="Send Email" name="submit"/> 
    </form>
```

Comment: @user2584238 you're welcome. and assuming your form is `.php` - I'm not sure if your form / PHP are inside the same file.

Comment: i tried your code but the thank you message always appears, even if i set the "sent" div to display:none.

Comment: @user2584238 give me a few minutes.

Comment: @user2584238 Pardon the wait. I realized that the logic needed to be reversed. First the PHP, then the HTML form. Reload my answer under the **Edit**. used exactly as shown.

Comment: It's still the same, message still appears on page load. Don't know what's wrong. I even put the message "div sent" inside position absolute in the center of the page and it still places it in the top left hand corner of the screen.

Comment: @user2584238 I've tested my edit before reposting. That should work. Did you in fact use my exact code or did you patch it? Copy/paste my edit exactly as shown. If you're not showing full code, then I won't be able to help you with what I don't know.

Comment: ohhhh, yes i see now. You added a name to the submit button. Yes it works! Thank you so much for your hard work. I appreciate it man :)

Comment: @user2584238 You're most welcome, glad I could help, *cheers* and all the best in the New Year.

Comment: all the best to you too ;)

Comment: @user2584238 Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```html
$password=md5($_POST ['password']);

$password3 =md5($_POST ['password2']);
if($password != $password3)
{
   $message = "Passwords do not match";

}

etc.

you need add 

<form>
<div class="form-group">
                                            <input type="password" name="password"  id="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password *" value="" required/>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <div class="message"><?php if(!empty($message)) { echo $message; } ?></div>
                                            <input type="password" name="password2" class="form-control" id="password2" placeholder="Confirm Password *" value="" required/>
                                        </div>
</form>
```

Comment: please edit your answer and split the code with you describe